# Steam keeps logging me out of the mobile application

Tags: steam, ios, steam-mobile

I have an IOS 10.3.3 iPhone 5s, and my steam app keeps logging me off.

I log back in but after a few minutes I get logged out again, and this is really irritating me.

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app?

Answer (score 2):

More of a superuser or apple.stackexchange question, but this is most likely because of [behavior of iOS itself](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6231782) and not the app. iOS automatically clears the cache on the least-used apps when the device is "low on space". I don't know how the iOS Steam app is setup, but maybe it's not separating the data properly -- have you tried submitting a bug report somehow, or talking to Steam Support?

The thread I linked to mentions estimations of the amount of free space for iOS 7, but it's up to 11 now so those numbers have likely changed.